# How to turn on detailed git logging in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio, logging

I have a need to examine the Git command sequence that VS2017 sends to my TFS 2018 instance.

Log verbosity settings in `Tools>Options` apply only to Build and Run actions. I tried Fiddler (it didn't pick up any packets at all); WireShark indicates that packets are sent via NTLM and therefore can't be displayed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you want, but it does seem to be possible to setup an audit log on the Git server itself, e.g. GitHub ([see here](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/)).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen—That got me thinking... "wouldn't it be nice if TFS had such a thing." So I went looking and found [this](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/09/20/audit-trail-on-tfs-source-control/). Alas, however, it turned out to be a dead-end. The database doesn't store individual Git commands, only more high-level sequence operations. Shucks.